# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL segment <route link>

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and i'm learning about the routing in angular. Made a basic application having few components and tried the routing. But the thing is that the links are not recognized and error is coming at the console, tried to look internet but all seems fine to me.
Please tell me where I need to correct the code.[image]

app.routing-module.ts class:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponentComponent } from './login-component/login-component.component';
import { RegistrationComponentComponent } from './registration-component/registration-component.component';
import { UsersComponentComponent } from './users-component/users-component.component';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { 

   routes: Routes  = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
    {path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponentComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponentComponent},
    {path: 'users',component: UsersComponentComponent}
  ];
}
```

app-component.html elements:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: grey;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card bg-dark my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title text-center text-white py-3">{{ title }}</h2>
          <ul class="text-center list-inline py-3">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a routerLink="registration" class="btn btn-info">Registration</a>
                </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a routerLink="login" class="btn btn-info">Login User</a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                  <a routerLink="users" class="btn btn-info">Existing Users</a>
                    </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and app-module.ts class:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UsersComponentComponent } from './users-component/users-component.component';
import { RegistrationComponentComponent } from './registration-component/registration-component.component';
import { LoginComponentComponent } from './login-component/login-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsersComponentComponent,
    RegistrationComponentComponent,
    LoginComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Move your routes array out of the module

instead of `const routes = [];`
put

```
  const routes: Routes  = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
    {path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponentComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponentComponent},
    {path: 'users',component: UsersComponentComponent}
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you initialize a `const array` of type `Routes`

```
    const routes: Routes = [];
```

Afterwards, you try to set the array to something else.

```
    routes: Routes  = [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
        {path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponentComponent},
        {path: 'login', component: LoginComponentComponent},
        {path: 'users',component: UsersComponentComponent}
      ];
```

Aside from the fact, that both `routes` lists are different, you dont get the below error due to the scope.

If you try fiddling around you will get the below error,

[image]

> TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

I'm just pointing this out because declaring a variable as const and later changing its value will not work, since it's declared as a constant.

Retry, initializing the array to it's default value from the start.

You can take a look at the official angular documentation, [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your routing configuration looks fine, however, ensure that you have a `<base href="/">` tag at the beginning of the `<head>` tag in `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases; the reason is that you are importing a lazy-module inside another lazy-module which itself is importing RouterModule.forChild(). This causes conflict with the parent module's routing.